# adding Xively java library to eclipse

Tags: java, xively

I am trying to use a [Xively Java library](https://github.com/xively/Xively4J) in Eclipse IDE, but I don't know how to make it work. I could not find any guidance or tutorial. Can someone give me a short guidance to put this library to eclipse and use it?

Answer (score 0):

right click your project on the left pane -> Properties -> Java Build Path -> Add Jars -> add your jars here.

Tadaa!! :)

Comment: Extract the jar, and put it somewhere in your Java project (usually under a "lib" subdirectory).

Right click the project, open its preferences, go for Java build path, and then the Libraries tab. You can add the library there with "add a jar".

If your jar is not open source, you may want to store it elsewhere and connect to it as an external jar.

Comment: It doesn't have any jar file. Is a rar file, and it contains one src folder inside. Should I just move this src somewhere? I tried to put it on my working space but it didn't work :(

Comment: Yes, there are snapshots available from [Sonatype repo](https://oss.sonatype.org/index.html#nexus-search;quick~xively).